https for just one aspx web forms application - IIS 10
We have a legacy web forms .aspx web application installed under "Default Web Site"
is it possible to enable https: for just this web application ? given that there are other web applications deployed under "Default Web Site"
All the instructions i found online insist upon creating a https: binding in IIS on port :443
The challenge is, I want to know is there any other possible way to enable https: for just that one web application without impacting the other applications ?

There's very little benefit to putting ONLY SOME pages on a website in HTTPS - it makes ssl stripping attacks trivial negating the justification for the exercise.

Assuming you are using IIS, the certificate is tied to the IP/Port binding, which is tied to the website; Default Web Site in your case.
If having a certificate on the site will break applications on the single IIS Site you're using, I would split the applications out to their own sites.
Just having the port and cert on the site doesn't force the site and subsequent apps to use the port and cert so, really, you should be fine.
